# How to add an 'on double clicked' event to an entire row in a QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, signals, signals-slots, slot

I want to add an 'on double clicked' event to each row in my QTableWidget. How can I do this?

The following function adds 1 row to the QTableWidget:

```
void ViewController::addReceivedFileToTable(QString sopInstanceUID, QString sopClassUID, QString fileName)
{
    m_mainWindow.getReceivedFilesTableWidget()->insertRow(0);
    m_mainWindow.getReceivedFilesTableWidget()->setItem(0,0,new QTableWidgetItem(sopInstanceUID));
    m_mainWindow.getReceivedFilesTableWidget()->setItem(0,1,new QTableWidgetItem(sopClassUID));
    m_mainWindow.getReceivedFilesTableWidget()->setItem(0,2,new QTableWidgetItem(fileName));
}
```

I need something like:

```
connect(m_mainWindow.getReceivedFilesTableWidget()->[getRow]->[onDoubleClicked], ....)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to connect to the doubleClicked signal which is available in the QAbstractItemView base class:

```
connect(m_mainWindow.getReceivedFilesTableWidget(), SIGNAL(doubleClicked(QModelIndex const&)), this, SLOT(onTableItemDoubleClicked(QModelIndex const&)));
```

Your implementation of onTableItemDoubleClicked will have to convert between the QModelIndex and the QTreeWidgetItem using QTableWidget::itemFromIndex.

Comment: What would this code be with the new signals-slots syntax?

Comment: Could you give me an example? How does Qt know what row is connected to the signal?

Comment: new syntax should be: connect(m_mainWindow.getReceivedFilesTableWidget(), &QAbstractItemView::doubleClicked, this, &ViewController::onDoubleClicked);

Comment: The slot will be called for any row that is double clicked. When you implement your slot, you must look at which row was double clicked by examining the slot's pass parameter.

Comment: QTableWidgetItem::row() or QModelIndex::row() can be use to get the row for the item.

Comment: So I need to pass the row (QTableWidgetItem::row() ) as a parameter to the slot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99534/discussion-between-engo-and-brad).

Comment: No, the slot's declaration includes a parameter of type QModelIndex. Use the row method on it to obtain which row was double clicked.